# What are the steps involved to manage a multiple chat server environment?

Tags: openfire

I am a SA newbie......  I have been tasked to write the steps involved or what is expected by an SA to manage a multiple chat server environment on OpenFire 3.6.4.  Please lend me your input on how to do this.  Thank you in advance for your assistance and help on this.

Guiseppe

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear. Some basics: you'll want a true SQL server like MySQL. Just avoid the internal one or you'll end up to reinstall OpenFire after a couple of months. If you plan to install it on Windows, you might want to run it as a service, there's an optional way to enable it (openfire-service.exe) The creation of rooms is very straightforward, after the installation of OpenFire, you'll be able to manage it through a web browser. As far as clients are concerned, there are plenty of them. Compatibility with Jabber/XMPP is required (Pidgin, Digsby, Pandion...)

Comment: you may want to have a look at the other xmpp chat servers too!